# Which form and when? "counterclockwise" vs "anticlockwise"

Tags: word-usage

Which term is more used in everyday English and which in formal/professional environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both mean the same, and there's no context where one would be preferred over the other. All you really need to know is that [Americans almost exclusively use **counterclockwise**...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=counterclockwise,anticlockwise&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

...whereas [Brits are just as happy using **anticlockwise**...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=counterclockwise,anticlockwise&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

But if you want to really impress people with your knowledge of obscure/dialectal/archaic forms, you might like to note that [widdershins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/widdershins) is another synonym.

Comment: As a note to the non-natives, FumbleFingers is being [tongue-in-cheek](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tongue-in-cheek) when he mentions "really impressing" people. Yes, _widdershins_ is an obscure synonym. No, most people won't be "impressed" if you use it.

Comment: I haven't heard anyone use “counterclockwise” in the UK. Is it American in origin?

Comment: @J.R.: I admit I was being a bit tongue in cheek there. But I can certainly imagine the likes of [RegDwight](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwigh) casually coming out with *widdershins* - that's the kind of thing that *does* impress me, considering he used to profile himself as a "native speaker" of two languages, *neither of which are English*.

Comment: @Tristan: If you toggle [this anti/counter-terrorist](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antiterrorist%2Canti-terrorist%2Ccounterterrorist%2Ccounter-terrorist&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) chart between UK/US corpora, I think you'll agree that Americans have a general preference for *counter-* rather than *anti-* in such contexts. But I find it surprising you've not heard Brits using “counterclockwise” - the charts above reflect my own preconception that we use both. I certainly do myself.

Comment: FF, maybe it's a regional thing and more common in your part of the world.

Comment: @Tristan: Could be. I'm in UK SE, and probably exposed to significant "internationalisation" from London (and Gatwick just up the road! :) My personal opinion is that given half a chance Americans prefer to shoe-horn a smaller number of "generic" prefixes/suffixes into a wider range of contexts, but that really is just an opinion - I've nothing to back it up.

Comment: FF, that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually type the keyword within double quotes and see the number of result. The larger number implies people prefers this one to another.

[image: counterclockwise]

[image: anticlockwise]

Comment: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/google-result-counts-are-a-meaningless-metric.html

Comment: @snailboat: oops, thx for the reference